# How to center align data with at least 15 spaces reserved with Tabulate in Python

Tags: python, printing

How do I print a table that has 15 spaces reserved for every field and data inside those fields also has to be centered?

Something like this:

```
        Name              Address      
--------------------  ---------------
        Abcd               Abcd
12345678901234567890       Abcd
```

Comment: 2 things:  what have you tried so far?  And what does your actual data look like?  A list of tuples will need different processing than a list of dicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `format`ting, `join` and list comprehension:

```py
headers = ['Name', 'Address']
value_lines = [
    ['Abcd', 'Abcd'],
    ['12345678901234567890', 'Abcd']
]

print(' '.join(['{:^25s}'.format(h) for h in headers]))
print(' '.join('-' * 25 for i in range(len(headers))))
for value_line in value_lines:
    print(' '.join(['{:^25s}'.format(value) for value in value_line]))
```

Output:

```
          Name                     Address         
------------------------- -------------------------
          Abcd                      Abcd           
  12345678901234567890              Abcd
```

If you need to increase column widths according to all values, it can be done this way:

```py
headers = ['Name', 'Address']
value_lines = [
    ['Abcd', 'Abcd'],
    ['12345678901234567890', 'Abcd']
]

column_widths = [15] * len(headers)
for i, header in enumerate(headers):
    column_widths[i] = max(column_widths[i], len(header))
for value_line in value_lines:
    for i, value in enumerate(value_line):
        column_widths[i] = max(column_widths[i], len(value))

print(' '.join([
    ('{:^' + str(column_widths[i]) + 's}').format(h)
    for i, h in enumerate(headers)
]))
print(' '.join('-' * column_widths[i] for i in range(len(headers))))
for value_line in value_lines:
    print(' '.join([
        ('{:^' + str(column_widths[i]) + 's}').format(value)
        for i, value in enumerate(value_line)
    ]))
```

Output:

```
        Name             Address    
-------------------- ---------------
        Abcd              Abcd      
12345678901234567890      Abcd
```

Comment: This code is good, but what I was trying to say is that each column *has* to be 15 characters long unless it overflows. In your example, the column 'Address' is as long as 'Name' which shouldn't be the case.

Comment: @VukMC added a variation with increase of columns width, updated answer.